# Validate XML with multiple namespace in Java

Tags: java, xml, validation, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate a XML document that uses multiple namespaces. I want to embed tags of the secondary namespace within a document of the primary namespace. The main/primary namespace does not "know" of the extension/secondary namespace.

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book
    xmlns    ="MyMain_FPI"
    xmlns:ns2="MyExtension_FPI"
    >
    <ns2:playmusic/>
    <chapter/>
    <chapter/>
</book>
```

The Java code for validation is the following:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new Source[] {
    new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("main.xsd")),
    new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("extension.xsd")),
});
factory.setSchema(schema);

DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = builder.parse(new File("test.xml"));
```

As you can see, I directly add the XSD files to the DocumentBuilderFactory.
Those files are:

**main.xsd**

```
<xs:schema 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns="MyMain_FPI"
  targetNamespace="MyMain_FPI"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="book">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="chapter"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="chapter">
    <xs:complexType/>    
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**extension.xsd**

```
<xs:schema 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns="MyExtension_FPI"
  targetNamespace="MyExtension_FPI"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="playmusic">
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The error I get when executing the code above is

```
[Error] test.xml:6:18: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Ungültiger Content wurde beginnend mit Element 'ns2:playmusic' gefunden. '{"MyMain_FPI":chapter}' wird erwartet.
```

Meaning, that  is unexpected within the main namespace - which is understandable, since the element itself is unknown in that namespace. I expected that elements of the extension namespace are ignored when validating the document again the main namespace and vice versa - meaning that I can embed documents following the extension namespace within the main namespace. But that is obviously not working.

What did I miss?

Comment: Your XSD says that your "book" element has a list of "chapter" elements.  You tried to put in a different element.  I'm not sure what you're question is.  Do you want to know how to rewrite `main.xsd` to allow playmusic?

Comment: I thought it would be possible to validate the document without rewriting the `main.xsd`. Both XSDs are not really related.

I assume I could write an XSD that combines both XSDs, but that would be annoying, since my real application might have several extension XSDs that might be present or not - and the list may be continued. (Think of it as embedded subdocuments for a kind of plugin).

My question is if there is any way to validate this, so that the validator won't complain about elements from the extension.xsd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `main.xsd` is explicit in what is allowed in the `book` element.  If you want to allow any additional element, you'll need to state that in the `main.xsd`.  After which you can add any extension XSDs you want.  see https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#any.

new main.xsd

```
<xs:schema 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns="MyMain_FPI"
targetNamespace="MyMain_FPI"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="book">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="chapter"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="chapter">
  <xs:complexType/>    
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you. The ANY element is a good compromise between keeping the main XSD to have no clue of possible extensions and still being valid although unknown (within `main.xsd`) elements appear in the document tree. This way I just need to define the possible extension points in the `main.xsd`.